# How to change testNG Reporter.log() encoding to UTF-16

Tags: java, logging, encoding, utf-8, testng

I am using testNG with selenium. I have two kind of logger, one is **log4j** logger and the other is **testNG Reporter.log()**. Now the problem is I need to log some Chinese text. But it is coming as '????' instead of Chinese text. So I changed the log4j.properties file, just added two lines:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-16
```

Now in my log4j logs it is coming properly but in testNG Reporter.log() it's still coming as '?????'.

**Log4j log:** Typed text '美联泰'

**TestNG Reporter.log():** Typed text '???'

How to set testNG Reporter.log() encoding to UTF-16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something else and now it's working. Just added `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable. Variable name: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` Variable value: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `Reporter#log(new String(s, "UTF-16"), level);` in the API?
See [String API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for details.

Comment: I have tried to convert the string to byte and then again from byte to string, but it's not working.

byte[] b = (chineseString).getBytes("US-ASCII");

Reporter.log(new String(b, "UTF-16"));

Comment: Did you also try `chineseString.getBytes("UTF-16"); Reporter.log(new String(b, "UTF-16"));`. Also are you sure that the target encoding is UTF-16 as Traditional chinese follows charset GB18030. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030

Comment: I tried something else and now it's working. Just added JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable.
Variable name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
Variable value:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF8