# Azure - Chinese character support in App Service Editor

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

I have spring boot jar deployed as web app in Microsoft azure, this jar is generating rolling log files at wwwroot location and is printing chinese characters as ??? in log files. Is there a way to print proper chinese characers in the log files ?

PS: The chinese characters are printed properly in the console logs in my local machine.

Comment: If it is resloved, you could add the answer here and mark it as an answer to help more communities.

Answer (score 0):

> this jar is generating rolling log files at wwwroot location and is printing chinese characters as ???

I suggest you could  try to set the default encoding on your server to UTF-8.
For more details,you could refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939555/how-to-config-spring-boot-application-to-support-both-utf-8-and-gbk-encode) to solve the issue about chinese characters in spring boot.

Comment: @user1635256 Could your provide related code or screenshot?

Comment: Its fixed by adding encoding UTF-8 to log4j.

Comment: What about this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27013487/how-to-change-testng-reporter-log-encoding-to-utf-16) and this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356309/spring-security-remember-me-cookie-unicode-characters-wrong).

Comment: If my answer is still helpful, you could vote it up or mark it as answer to help other people find. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added UTF-8 encoding to my log4j2.xml and it worked.

`<Configuration>
  <PatternLayout ..... charset="UTF-8"/>
</Configuration>`